# Rokugan's Light Cavalry

Tags: mounted-combat, l5r-4e, rokugan

*Sword and Fan* does offer a lot of military background for Rokugan. Including the following excerpt:

> Light cavalry is a staple of any Rokugani army, even
> if it otherwise has little in the way of mounted warriors. <sup>[1]</sup>

This implies each and every clan has cavalry. For most clans, they even give a renowned unit name. But the only clan that actually has any cavalry school in the core book is of course unicorn with both their Moto and Utaku schools <sup>[2]</sup>. The rest of the chapter contains cavalry unit names and descriptions, but the Table of contents does not indicate there are any new schools included.

This leads to the question:

**Where are the rules for those schools, paths, or alternate schools that are dedicated cavalry and not from clan unicorn?**

---

1 - Sword & Fan, p.72
2 - L5R 4E Core, p.130 & p.132

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are actually in the very same book, but the Table of Contents is breaking with convention:

While usually, new schools would be marked in the Table of contents under the *Appendix: New mechanics* heading (or as a sub-chapter with the *New Game Mechanics title*), Sword and Fan broke with that: They are in the chapter *Appendix* under the subtitle *New Advantages* (which usually contains **only** new advantages, in S&F that is one). The problem is, that it puts the clans as Level 3 headlines under the advantages, implying that there are advantages and drawbacks in the subchapter. It's also breaking the tradition of listing all the contained schools like the element books series, as shown below:

[image]

Four of the (non-unicorn) named cavalry units actually have a school in those clan-subchapters, making them rather hidden:

- Crab - Tsuru's Legion - Bushi Alternate path 2 - page 202
- Dragon - Dragon's Wind - Bushi Alternate path 3/4 - page 205
- Mantis - Orochi Riders - ANY Alternate path 5/6 - page 206
- Imperial - The Rising Sun - Bushi Alternate path 5 - page 210

This means Doji's Fans, Lion Wardens, and Tsunami Legion have no special ability belonging to them in this book.